# How to clear form after submit when validation fails but still display error message MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, contact-form

I'm trying to have a contact form (MVC )that will reload the View if it fails validation. That works. However if you go back to the page and correct your error, the ModelState is still false on submit so it's just reloading the page.

I tried doing `ModelState.Clear` before the return, but that will clear the errors. I need a way to show the error, and THEN clear the model, but ofcourse I cant use that method after returning.

My code below:

```
public ActionResult Index(ContactFormViewModel model, string inputFirstName, string inputLastName, string inputEmail, string inputMessage)
{                  
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
            return View("Success");
    }
    //reload page and show validation errors
    else
    {
        return View(model);
    }            
}
```

For example, in my Model, I have a regex on the Message field with error message. If I first type something that is not allowed, ModelState is false and returns View (correct). However, go back to the form and correct issue, ModelState should now be true but it is still `false`.

If I do

```
else
{
    ModelState.Clear()
    return View(model);
}
```

then the page reloads with no error messages. This is not ideal.

How do I get it so that the error message is displayed and then the modelState is clear.

I tried `ContactFormViewModel cmModel = new ContactFormViewModel()` but this had the same result.

Comment: It just means you have another `ModelState` error. Inspect the value of `ModelState` to see all the errors. And why are you not using client side validation to prevent the submit if there are validation errors?

Comment: I do, I just removed a lot of code for the purpose of this question

Comment: how about return View(new ContactFormViewModel());

Comment: @PraneetNadkar, That dos not change `ModelState`.

Comment: As it stands the question is not answerable

Comment: well someone just answered it so...

Comment: @PraneetNadkar that worked! Can you put your answer in the answers so that I can vote it

Comment: @user2903379, That cannot possibly solve the problem you have described (the `HtmlHelper` methods use the values from `ModelState`, and will ignore a new instance of `ContactFormViewModel` - clearly there are problems with your view which you have not shown us

Comment: Actually it didnt really solve it..

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
return View(new ContactFormViewModel());
```

Create a new object and pass it to the view.

Comment: Actually, as Stephen pointed out, this didnt work because the State is still not valid

Answer (score 0):

After debugging, I found that the ModelState.IsValid was correctly showing as not valid because actually, the string I entered in the inputMessage did not satisfy the regex.
The answer had nothing to do with the model at all.